# Sed search and replace within variable that contains multiple lines and backslashes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following 2 Bash variables:

```
OLD="netgroup2\
    (,user1,) (,user2,) (,user3,) (,user4,) (,user5,) (,user6,) (,user7,) \
    (,user8,) (,user9,) (,user10,) (,user11,)"


NEW="netgroup2\
    (,user1,) (,user2,) (,user3,) (,user4,) (,user5,) (,user6,) (,user7,) \
    (,user8,) (,user9,) (,user10,) (,user11,) (,user12,)"
```

I am trying to replace the contents of $OLD with $NEW using sed, but the combination of backslashes and newlines is really making it difficult. Any help with how to achieve this is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I am trying (but is failing):

```
echo "$OLD" | sed "N; s#$OLD#$NEW#"
```

Edit: The variable $NEW is representing an existing NIS netgroup in a netgroup file that contains netgroups, so actual replacement is required

Comment: What about `OLD="$NEW"`?

Comment: Sorry, for clarification NEW is getting dumped into a net group NIS file that contains other netgroups, so replacement is a requirement

Comment: Do you mean you can have user in $OLD that are not present in $NEW ? Can you give a relevant usecase where @Cyrus proposition is wrong ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel  No, this is just for adding users to a netgroup. The sed command is going to eventually be used to replace the netgroup in a file. This file contains other netgroups that should not be modified. As a result, I planned on using the assistance here to then do a search and replace in the file.